# How to save the file to a specific folder (Network Drive or local folder) on a client machine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-cloud-services

I have an asp.net web app which is published as an Azure cloud service.The application downloads the files from the server and saves it locally on the client machine.However,It does not seem to work when published as a cloud service.It works fine when published locally using IIS.
The code below is the where the file gets saved.

```
 foreach (var item in userids)
        {
          //item.contractorpath= user filepath(client machine path eg, C:\test\)
         string filePath = 
         Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Downloads"), 
         SessionInfo.CompanyId.ToString(), "Bill", 
         item.ContractorId.ToString());

         if (Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
            //System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
            FileInfo[] TXTFiles = di.GetFiles("*.pdf");

            if (TXTFiles.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo file in TXTFiles)
                {
                    string fileName = file.Name;
                    if (!Directory.Exists(item.FolderPath))
                    {

                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(item.FolderPath);
                    }
                    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                    {
                        webClient.DownloadFile(Path.Combine(filePath, file.Name), Path.Combine(item.FolderPath, file.Name));

                        System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(filePath, file.Name));
                    }
                }
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: You are downloading the file “locally” on the server, not client computer. Any error ocurres when mentioned code is executed?

Comment: @LukasNespor Nope when i download locally on the server,it works fine.But is there a way i can download it to the client machine?